# Idle timeout on console session

Tags: windows-7, session

Have a situation developing where it would be useful to impose a automatic logout of a console session after a certain idle period.  The people logging in to the computer are logging in to it physically and not via RDP.  This means they are starting a console session and all the normal session limits I can impose via GP only apply to the remote terminal sessions.

Is there any mechanic whereby a user on a console session can be forcibly logged out after say 30 minutes idle time?

(OS is Windows 7 in a domain environment)

Answer (score 1):

Do a search for `Win7exit.scr` – it's a screen saver that you can apply through GPO but will have the effect of logging the User off instead of displaying a screensaver.

It is customisable as well.